# Painel de reputação do perfil, aba participação com layout quebrado

Tags: bug, status-pronto, layout, perfil

Ao visualizar o perfil, na aba de participação o layout está quebrado, com o texto do próximo privilégio mal posicionado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Isso acontece no Google Chrome 68, Firefox 61 e IE 11, os que eu testei.

Comment: O problema também existe no Chrome 67

Comment: Chrome 67.0.3396.99 aqui e isso não ocorre. Mas há um update, vou atualizar e ver se o problema passa a ocorrer.

Comment: Atualizei pro 68 e nao ocorreu, estranho.

Comment: No Opera 54.0.2952.64 ocorre o mesmo problema.

Comment: Chrome 67 aqui e acontece esse problema, atualizando pro 68...

Comment: Atualizado (68) e continua.

Comment: Confirmado.....

Comment: Suponho que "talvez" tenha se confundido @Articuno o problema depende se o seu score é abaixo de 20k e se esta na tela do perfil principal e não do Meta, usuarios como vc que já tem todos privilégios isto não é mostrado, mas se entrar em perfis com menos score vai notar o problema. No Chrome 68.0.3440.84 (versão mais atual até aqui) ocorre o problema ainda.

Comment: Só pra descontrair, @Articuno atingiu o privilégio "imune à quebra de layout" :)

Comment: Parece que foi corrigido. Embora não tenha uma resposta, agora o layout está ok pra mim, podem confirmar por favor?

Comment: Realmente, pude testar o bug e estava ocorrendo mesmo, mas não sabia q era apenas em alguns perfis, e acabei testando apenas no meu. Agora não está mais ocorrendo, testei em varios perfiss reputação de 1 a 4 digitos e nao ocorreu mais, corrigiram, aparentemente.

Comment: @Articuno foi corrigido mesmo! Testei aqui os perfis que notei o problema e parece estar tudo ok agora.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como já confirmamos que está ok, estou respondendo para dizer que esse problema foi corrigido e foi rápido.

Comment: Só faltou aceitar